# How do I put a time delay into my script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a 3 second delay in my script

However how can I do this, I don't know!

My script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var baslik = document.title;
    $(document).ready(function () {

        document.title = '(Welcome)' + baslik; // After 3 seconds 
        document.title = '(What can i do for you ?)' + baslik; // After 3 seconds
        document.title = '(Thank u for viewing to me)' + baslik; // After 3 seconds 
        document.title = baslik;
    });         
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, your question has been downvoted a bit, this is probably because you've not explained what you've already tried to solve the problem. Even if you've no idea what code to write, have you tried Googling to find useful information? If so, including that into your question will make it a better question. The right queries make all the difference, and I see that originally you asked about a "certain time interval", which would normally be called a "time delay"

Comment: I have removed your down votes, but be sure that next time when you ask any questions, make it detailed.. add maximum information and make it clear.
Be careful while using this site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use Timeout http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

```
var baslik = document.title;
postMsg = function(txt) {
   document.title = txt + baslik;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout("postMsg('(Welcome)')",3000);
  setTimeout("postMsg('(What can i do for you ?)')",6000);
  setTimeout("postMsg('(Thank u for viewing to me)')",9000);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `setTimeout` method

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     setTimeout(function(){

        var baslik = document.title;    
         document.title = '(Welcome)' + baslik; // After 3 seconds 
         document.title = '(What can i do for you ?)' + baslik; // After 3 seconds 
         document.title = '(Thank u for viewing to me)' + baslik; // After 3 seconds 
         //document.title = baslik;       

    },3000);
});
```

Comment: This wouldn't have a delay between each message, but just show the last one after 3 seconds. From the sound of it, the OP wanted a 3 second delay between each one.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do the trick,

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

var baslik = document.title;
var welcomeMessages = ['(Welcome)',
                '(What can i do for you ?)',
                '(Thank u for viewing to me)' ];
var timer; 
var msgPt = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
     timer = setInterval(function () {
         if (msgPt == welcomeMessages.length) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            document.title = baslik;
            return;
         }
         document.title = welcomeMessages[msgPt++];
     }, 3000);             
});


</script>
```